# MVVM: How can I retrieve the values from a textbox that I manually entered on a listview where item is checked?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a listview that is populated with Cars. There is 3 columns.. 1. Checkbox Column, 2. Car Name, 3. Textbox Column for car price.

I am trying to enter all of these data into the db via Entity Framework. I need to retrieve all the data including car prices if column is checked.

For example:

I have 2 Columns that is checked. I enter the car price in the textboxes that are related to the column. I then click the save button so it would enter 2 columns in the database, with car name and car price. How can I approach that?

**View XAML**

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" Height="100">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Car Name">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                            <ContentControl.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Car}">
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CarStringConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="CarName" />
                                                <Binding Path="CarMake" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContentControl.Resources>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding CarPrice}" >
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Property of my ViewModel

```
    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> cars;
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Cars
    {
        get { return cars; }
        set
        {
            cars = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Cars);
        }
    }
```

The cars collection is being passed into. It's from an existing table.

Calling this will give me the selected cars that I checked on my view.
Cars.Where((x) => x.IsSelected == true)

My list is populated with data from the cars collection, there will be a checkbox that I check and an empty textbox will come out. I will enter data in that textbox and click save. I'm not sure how I can pass that data from that textbox to my viewmodel.

Comment: guess my overall question is, how do I databind a textbox that is inside a listview.

Comment: Show us your xaml and code. This will help us, help you. And check update source trigger on your binding. On TextBox by default its on lost focus. Maybe change that to PropertyChanged.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Please look at my edit post. There's a same of my code. Think the bigger picture is receiving data from text box into the viewmodel. If I check two cars and enter their prices in the textbox, I need to obtain it in the viewmodel so I can use that data to enter into the db.

Comment: When you get your cars.where(x => x.Selected) then CarPrice property will have that value. Though I am thinking you might be asking a different question here

Comment: Can you show us how you get cars in your view model?

Comment: I figured it out. I was binding the listview to an list that did not contain CarPrice. I had to create my own unique class with the CarPrice property in it.

Comment: So you couldn't extend the class that you were already using?